# What is the point of changing the manga's storyline for the adaptation?

Tags: anime-production

As the title states, why do producers/script writers working on an anime adaptation change diverge from the story in the manga?, may it be small or a huge change.From a logical perspective  when adapting an anime, changing the storyline from the source makes no sense at all, since it may have been what made it so popular in the first place. So why do they do it?. *Cough cough promised neverland*.

Answer (score 1):

Among other reasons:

1. The story is too long to fit in the number of shows they have
2. Scenes or other elements are not cinematic.  (This is less a problem than with novels, since manga's a visual medium.  Still the change in media may mean that some scenes don't work.)
3. Censorship, whether legal or corporate.  Some things may just not be allowed.
4. Changing or broadening the audience.  A manga can be niche but an anime needs a broad audience for the expense.  Also, whoever's in charge of the adaption may be sure they can bring in new fans with changes, and not alienate the base.